# Why Milestone clock is not running?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I have created an Entitlement Process and Milestones, but the clock is not ticking up, What could be the reason ? I really need a quick help.

The milestones are showing uo

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out what is the issue is. Actually all my milestone are currently using US Business hour and in that business hour there I have not given any time for the weekends, so today is Saturday and thats why milestones time is not showing. So issues at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Milestone clock is running properly.

For Completed Milestones, time remaining will be always zero.

Those milestones which are in progress, time remaining will be shown in that.

Refer [CaseMilestone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casemilestone.htm) documentation for more info.